# Whats the php equivalent of $_ in perl?

Tags: php, arrays, perl, variables, loops

In Perl, you can reference the current variable of a loop via `$_`

For example:

```
my @array = (1,2,3,4);
foreach(@array)
{
    print $_." ";
}
```

Will print:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Is there a php equivalent for this?

Comment: Damnnnn, so many downvotes? It is prob. an honest question by someone coming from perl to php. You guys are harsh.

Comment: @zerkms: but stackoverflow can become a FM for people to R, and questions like this help.  This has been closed as "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" (and is none of those things) "and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" (completely false).

Comment: @ysth: so let's create a question for every single php function and language construction just for people to R. PS: it was closed with this reason just because there is no reason (yet) like "OP was too lazy to spend a minute to google the answer"

Comment: guess what, if there is no close reason that applies, that means under current rules, it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: In Perl, you would use `print join " ", @array;` or even just `print "@array";` for that. It also avoids the trailing space.

Comment: @dubvfan87: what happens with this world if questions that can be answered in 10 seconds by reading manual are suitable here?

Comment: @dubvfan87: I doubt so. Some time ago SO didn't encourage RTFM-like questions.

Comment: @* - The questions that seem (or are) easy to find via search engines &| manuals are posted only after I've spent 5-10 minutes using search engines and not finding the answer.  Then I post the question on SO and continue to use search engines while waiting for answers.  Sometimes I end up finding and posting my own answer regardless of other users' suggestions.  I know the `$_` is used for, but also don't know the proper name for it effectively making search terms more difficult to narrow down relevant results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value . ' ';
}
```

http://php.net/foreach